# Forma recomendada para popular variáveis com dados do banco

Tags: c#, sql, .net, variáveis, ado.net

Supondo esse método ficticio para obter dados do banco, digamos que SQL Server:

```
  public List<DadosDTO> ObterDados()
    {
        try
        {
            comand = connectionFactory.CreateCommand();
            comand.CommandText = "SELECT intDado, stringDado, dateDado, doubleDado FROM TB_DADOS";
            comand.Connection = connection;
            dataReader = comand.ExecuteReader();

            List<DadosDTO> LstDados = new List<DadosDTO>();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                DadosDTO dados = new DadosDTO();

                //Popular variáveis aqui.                     

                LstDados.Add(dados);
            }

            return LstDados;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Existe um padrão recomendado para se popular as variáveis? Uma forma mais correta e otimizada? Essa forma que eu estruturei o método é o melhor ou existe outra forma?

Minha pergunta visa aprender a melhor forma de fazer e o porquê, então se alguém souber e puder explicar...

Comment: Eu pelo menos faço da mesma forma que tu e nunca me questionei/lembrei sobre uma forma mais otimizada. Boa pergunta

Comment: O correto (mais recomendado) é você ter uma consulta que já retorne pra você o objeto que você deseja fazer o select e atribuir direto à ele...se esperar até a noite te mando um exemplo legal.

Comment: @Dante é isso que ele está fazendo...

Comment: Não posso dizer com 100% de certeza, mas isso me parece um caso de micro otimização: se sua consulta é bem formada, só retorna as colunas relevantes, etc, tirar do *result set* e colocar nas variáveis é algo negligível em comparação. Em relação à performance, creio que não há com o que se preocupar. Mas a pergunta permanece válida na minha opinião, uma vez que deve haver meios mais e menos concisos e "elegantes" de fazê-lo, talvez até mesmo *type safe*... (deixo pra quem entende de C# responder)

Comment: Mas, acredito que se ele atribuir direto no momento da consulta, não precise passar pelo While e ficar fazendo o ADD.

Comment: @Dante, fico no aguardo para ver o seu exemplo sem o While!

Answer (score 4):

Paulo, não sei se existe uma forma mais otimizada, mas no seu exemplo de código, existem algumas coisas que podem ser protegidas para garantir um consumo mais baixo de memória e otimização do código.

Fiz um pseudo código no bloco de notas e não sei se ele tem algum erro, caso tenha, me desculpe.

Vou dar uma breve explicação:

Utilize a clausula ***using*** sempre que possível. Ela vai garantir que o objeto criado na declaração da mesma, seja utilizado dentro de seu escopo e que ao sair dele, este objeto seja marcado para ser destruído.

Nesse exemplo eu consultei os valores do select utilizando o índice da coluna do resultado. Esta é a forma mais veloz, contudo é a pior para manutenção, pois se você mudar a ordem das colunas no comando de consulta ou se inserir um novo campo no meio, vai mudar todos os índices. Ou seja, use com cuidado e oriente sua equipe para só adicionar campos no final.

O ***yield return dados;*** é utilizado em métodos cujo retorno seja IEnumerable, ele é uma faca de dois gumes. O yield faz com que seu comando seja executado com atraso. Mas o que seria isso. No momento em que você executa o método de ***ObterDados*** ele vai "preparar" o método para ser executado e te retornar um objeto de IEnumerable mas enquanto você não acessar o mesmo, ele não irá disparar a consulta em si. Ou seja, em um caso em que você tenha um objeto que possui uma propriedade que é uma lista de objetos, ele só executará a consulta no momento em que esses dados realmente forem lidos. Mas qual é o outro lado da moeda? O método vai ser disparado todas as vezes que você fizer acesso a propriedade. Com isso ao invés de uma só consulta, você fará várias. Existem na Internet diversos exemplos bem completos de como contornar isso.

Segue meu código:

---

```
public IEnumerable<DadosDTO> ObterDados()
{
    try
    {
        using (IDbCommand dbCommand = connectionFactory.CreateCommand())
        {
            dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT intDado, stringDado, dateDado, doubleDado FROM TB_DADOS";
            dbCommand.Connection = connection;
            using (IDataReader dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    var dados = new DadosDTO {
                        ValorInteiro = dataReader.GetInt32(0),
                        ValorString = dataReader.GetString(1)
                    };

                    yield return dados;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```